# Neo4j cypher query order by with collect

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In cypher query i have multiple result which i get using collect now how i can order by collect property in cypher?

```
MATCH(u:User) 
WITH COLLECT({name:u.name,date:u.date}) AS userinfo 
RETURN userinfo
```

OR in the case there are multiple collections that have been merged

```
MATCH(u:User)-[r:CreatedBy]->(p:Project) 
WITH COLLECT({name:p.name,date:p.date}) AS info 
MATCH(i:Institue)-[owner:Owner]->(i:Institute) 
WITH COLLECT({instituteName:i.name,date:i.date}) AS instituteinfo,info 
WITH COLLECT(instituteinfo + info) AS alldata 
RETURN alldata
```

Comment: Is your goal is to order the items in the collection?

Comment: yes @Dave Bennet

Comment: Suppose i have multiple collection and i merge all collection then how can i order by it like : 
`MATCH(u:User)-[r:CreatedBy]->(p:Project)
WITH COLLECT({name:p.name,date:p.date}) AS info
MATCH(i:Institue)-[owner:Owner]->(i:Institute)
WITH COLLECT({instituteName:i.name,date:i.date})
AS instituteinfo,info
WITH COLLECT(instituteinfo + info) AS alldata
RETURN alldata`
in this query i want order by date

Answer (score 9):

You simply need to order the user nodes by the attribute of your choice prior to collecting them. Something like this..,

```
MATCH(u:User)
WITH u
ORDER BY u.name
WITH COLLECT({name:u.name,date:u.date}) AS userinfo 
RETURN userinfo
```

Or if you were looking to combine multiple collections and produce a single ordered collection you could recombine them something like this...

```
MATCH(u:User)-[r:CreatedBy]->(p:Project) 
WITH COLLECT({name:p.name, date:p.date}) AS info 
MATCH(i:Institue)-[owner:Owner]->(i:Institute) 
WITH COLLECT({instituteName:i.name, date:i.date}) AS instituteinfo,info 
WITH instituteinfo + info AS alldata 
UNWIND alldata as node
WITH node
ORDER BY node.name
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT node) as alldata
RETURN alldata
```

Comment: No because suppose i have multiple collection so in that case how can i do order by e.g
``

Comment: Suppose i have multiple collection and i merge all collection then how can i order by it like : MATCH(u:User)-[r:CreatedBy]->(p:Project) WITH COLLECT({name:p.name,date:p.date}) AS info MATCH(i:Institue)-[owner:Owner]->(i:Institute) WITH COLLECT({instituteName:i.name,date:i.date}) AS instituteinfo,info WITH COLLECT(instituteinfo + info) AS alldata RETURN alldata in this query i want order by date

Comment: If you have follow on information that is really pertinent to your question you should just update your question and use the comment to refer to the update rather than post a bunch of Cyper in a comment.  In the case of multiple collections that you want to combine and order, you need to combine them and unwind them, order them and then re-collect them.